# How AbstractTableModel works?

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I couldn't Get my head around how AbstractTableModel  works,
it implements : getValueAt(),getColumnClass(),getColumnName(),etc..
what I didn't understand how JTable takes the data and meta data from The result Set and show them.
The methods in AbstractTableModel all of them are getters so how the values are set?

for example in "Java How to Program" book,
There is a code for AbstractTableModel in page 1233, and he created this method in it

```
public void setQuery( String query )
145 throws SQLException, IllegalStateException
146 {
147 // ensure database connection is available
148 if ( !connectedToDatabase )
149 throw new IllegalStateException( "Not Connected to Database" );
150
151 // specify query and execute it
152 resultSet = statement.executeQuery( query );
153
154 // obtain meta data for ResultSet
155 metaData = resultSet.getMetaData();
156
157 // determine number of rows in ResultSet
158 resultSet.last(); // move to last row
159 numberOfRows = resultSet.getRow(); // get row number
160
161
162
163 } // end method setQuery
Fig. 28.25 | A TableModel that supplies ResultSet data to a JTable. (Part 4 of 5.)
public int getRowCount()
public Object getValueAt( int row, int column )
resultSet.absolute( row + 1 );
return resultSet.getObject( column + 1 );
// notify JTable that model has changed
fireTableStructureChange
```

and when he decaled the jtable in the other class,and set the model for it,
he just used The setQuery Method that he has created and The meta data and rows of the table has changed automatically.

Comment: `JTable` doesn't take anything from "the result set" - it takes all information from the `TableModel`.  The intention of `AbstractTableModel` is to provide a basic, abstract, implementation of the core, most commonly repeated/boil plate code and leave the remaining functionality up to future implementations.  `AbstractTableModel` also, doesn't implement `getValueAt`, `getValueAt`, `getRowCount` and `getColumnCount` are marked as `abstract` and you are expected to implement those.

Comment: Think of it this way - the `TableModel` sits between the `JTable` and your data and provides the contract through which you can get you data, in what ever format it is, presented on the table in common way

Comment: *"how the values are set?"* Look at [`DefaultTableModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/DefaultTableModel.html) for an example.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank You. I tried to clarify my question in the original post.

Comment: From the looks of it, the implementation is using `ResultSet` as the backing data, although calling the `setQuery` method should be calling `fireTableStructureChange` to cause the `JTable` to rebuild itself.  There must be more to the implementation, `getValueAt` should be implemented and I imagine at least `getColumnName` as well

Comment: @MadProgrammer Yeah You are correct they are implemented ,all of them, so what you are saying that those methods plays a rule in setting the values of the table?

Comment: Of course they do - look at the `TableModel` `interface`, this is the minimal contractual requirements that any implementation of a `TableModel` MUST have